# Coercing column types during UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to add some new data to a table, and the most recent import contains 4 new columns. In the script below, I'm trying to create placeholders for the new columns within the historical data, then union the historical and imported tables into a new master.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Historical ADD dimension1 varchar(255) NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Historical ADD measure1 decimal(28,15) NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Historical ADD measure2 decimal(28,15) NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Historical ADD measure3 decimal(28,15) NULL;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Master') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.Master

SELECT *
INTO dbo.Master
FROM dbo.Historical
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Import
```

When I run this code, the union step causes the following error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 38
> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

The error is coming from the union step, specifically because the type for dimension1 in the newly-created `dbo.Master` is `decimal(28,15)`. How can I force dimension1 to be `varchar(255)` and accept the union?

Comment: Ummm... `convert`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `select *` and explicitly convert the columns.

```
select cast(dimension1 as varchar(255)) dimension1,
       measure1,
       measure2,
       measure3
into dbo.Master
from dbo.Historical
union ALL
select dimension1,
       measure1,
       measure2,
       measure3
from dbo.Import
```